# Applications search doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Applications searching in Ubuntu 18.04 no longer works. This is a new install that has few modifications. The applications search feature hasn't worked from the initial installation for some reason.

**Expected results:** Type in a search term, such as "Settings" and see a filtered list of applications. In this case I should only see the Settings app.

**Actual Results:** No filtering is performed, all apps (either recent or all) continue to display.

Is there a way to fix this so that the search bar filters the results as it did in 17.10?

[image]

More info from `journalctl -f`

```
May 27 00:49:59 ComputerName gnome-shell[28923]: JS ERROR: TypeError: display is undefined   _updateSearchProgress/haveResults<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/search.js:645:13    _updateSearchProgress@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/search.js:643:27
wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
setTerms@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/search.js:565:9
wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
_onTextChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/viewSelector.js:532:9
wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1771278

Apparently I had installed the VSCode Search Provider but had it disabled. Even with it disabled it caused errors. After uninstalling it with the Software Center and rebooting I was able to search again. Please be aware that the application search did not work until rebooting, but logging out and back in may also work.

Comment: This "fix" didn't stick, and the search bar stopped working again. Since I'm not a fan of always customizing my Dock, I'd rather not attempt to use this option again.